# Downsample tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, downsampling

I need to downsample a tensor by a factor 2, it is a 1-D tensor:
[image]

I don't know how can I do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `tensor[::2]` subsamples a tensor by 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using interpolation, the easiest way to do it would be through average pooling. Learn more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/AveragePooling1D).

Answer (score 0):

What you are you are looking for is probably `tf.squeeze(tensor)`, which removes the dimensions that are 1